# What is this error: curl: (26) read function returned funny value parse error: premature EOF

Tags: api, rest, curl

When executing underneath, i get this error and i do not find much online about it.

```
[user@vm itop_api]$ curl -k -K curlopt.txt -X POST -F 'version=1.3' https://vma04.domain/webservices/rest.php -F 'json_data=@./get_server2a.json' |json_reformat

Warning: setting file ./get_server2a.json  failed!
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   272    0     0    0   272      0   9714 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9379

curl: (26) read function returned funny value
parse error: premature EOF
    
                         (right here) ------^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After double checking all values entered, while making this post, i just realised the actual file `json_data=@./get_server2a.json` does not exist.

Maybe this helps somebody running into the same silly mistake.

Comment: for me it was the file was not readable, permission issue